# Truncating a posterior predictive distribution in JAGS

Tags: bayesian, jags, posterior

I have run into an error associated with truncating a distribution in JAGS.

In my minimum reproducible example, I have data for 9 observations and would like to find a posterior predictive distribution for the 10th observation. To do this, I include the 10th observation as an NA and estimate its posterior predictive distribution as the variable `pi10`.

```
jagsdata <- data.frame(Y = c(47, 126, 68, 43, 67, 80, 61, 9, 26, NA))

model.string <- "
model{
 for (k in 1:10){
    Y[k]  ~ dlnorm(Z[k], tau.sp[k])
    tau.sp[k] ~ dgamma(0.01,0.01)
    Z[k] <- beta.o + beta.sp[k]
 }
  for (g in 1:10) {
    beta.sp[g] ~ dnorm(0, 0.0001)
  }
  beta.o    ~ dgamma (2, 0.04)
  pi10   <- Y[10]
}
"
writeLines(model.string, con = 'jagstest.bug')

library(rjags)
j.model  <- jags.model(file = "jagstest.bug", 
                       data = jagsdata, 
                       n.adapt = 500, 
                       n.chains = 4)
mcmc.object <- coda.samples(model = j.model,
                            variable.names = c('pi10'),
                            n.iter = 5000)
```

This works, but I would like to truncated the distribution of Y, for example by using the `T(1,200)`. However replacing line 4 above with

```
    Y[k]  ~ dlnorm(Z[k], tau.sp[k])T(1,200)
```

gives the error:

```
Unobserved node inconsistent with unobserved parents at initialization
```

Although Y with a normal distribution does not give an error.

```
    Y[k]  ~ dnorm(Z[k], tau.sp[k])T(1,200)
```

I have read through the [JAGS manual section 7](http://ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/FreeBSD/distfiles/mcmc-jags/jags_user_manual.pdf) and some examples online, but it is not clear to me how to implement this or why I am getting this error.

Suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I believe it is due to the way you sample $Z[k]$.

Comment: @teucer can you be more specific? Am I making an error in model specification?

Comment: @jbowman Any chance you have a literature source you reference for posterior pruning? I have a similar problem as that presented here and I used the solution you suggested (thank you!) but I would really like to read up more about it and provide a justification with a reference in my write up. Thank you for your time and assistance. "You can avoid this problem altogether by sampling from the untruncated distribution of Y[k], then (in R) discarding all samples for which Y[k] doesn't lie within the constraint bounds. This is a perfectly valid operation, however, if you have few posterior observa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid this problem altogether by sampling from the untruncated distribution of `Y[k]`, then (in R) discarding all samples for which `Y[k]` doesn't lie within the constraint bounds.  This is a perfectly valid operation, however, if you have few posterior observations in the feasible region, you'll naturally have a large simulation error associated with your posterior distribution(s).

As a side note, you might want to avoid the Gamma(0.01,0.01) prior on the variance; see for example this [presentation](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/presentations/weakpriorstalk.pdf) by Andrew Gelman and this [paper](http://www.stat.rice.edu/~marina/stat522/gelman.pdf), also by Gelman, for reasons why and alternative suggestions.

Comment: Hi jbowman ; do you happen to remember which paper your second link refers to (as its now dead) - long shot I know, but thanks

Comment: Oh, sure, let me dig it up and post the name as well as the link.

Comment: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/taumain.pdf,  "Prior distributions for variance parameters in hierarchical models" in Bayesian Analysis (2006) 1, No. 3, p. 515-533.